# Laravel 8 route exists but does nothing upon click

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8. I am creating a CRM. I have the welcom page with a link to the (index) dashboard. Once in the dashboard, I have a link to create a prospect. When I hover over the link, I can see that the route is correct, ie, mysite.test/prospects/create
When I click on the link, nothing happens. I get no error nor messages in the console. I am sure it is something silly or simple but I just can't seem to find out the problem. Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Here is my code:
In my app.blade.php I have -

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a href="{{ route('admin.prospects.dashboard') }}" class="dropdown-item">Manage Prospects</a>
 </div>
```

In my index.blade.php, I have -

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.prospects.create') }}">Create Prospect</a>
 </div>
```

prospects.php -

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Prospects\ProspectsController;


// Prefix: prospects
// name: admin.prospects.create

Route::get('/', [ProspectsController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('create', [ProspectsController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
```

ProspectsController.php -

```
    public function create()
    {
        // Go to prospects creation form
        return view('admin.prospects.create');

    }
```

And finally, my web.php file -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('prospects')->middleware('auth')->name('admin.prospects.')->group(base_path('routes/web/prospects.php'));
```

my view folder structure is -
resources - views - admin - prospects - then blade files

Comment: Try doing `dd('accessing')` or anything similar before doing `return view` just to make sure the desired controller is been executed.

Comment: like this? 
```
public function create()
    {
        // Go to prospects creation form
        dd('accessing');
        return view('admin.prospects.create');

    }
```

Comment: Yes, and see if you get that `accessing` back as a response on the page

Comment: No. Unfortunatelly, I don't access anything. I can click a million times and go nowhere.

Comment: Can you manually access that URL and see it ?

Comment: Yes I can. I follow the route as it appears as I hover over the link.

Comment: Then you have javascript preventing that `<a>` tag to work as a link

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had an issue in my dropdown menu which wasn't allowing my route to proceed. I changed it to the following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Create Prospect</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.prospects.create') }}">Dashboard</a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

And now it routes just fine. Thank you @matiaslauriti for pointing me in the right direction.